# stringstream loses precision while converting

Tags: c++, precision, stringstream

I have a small problem with stringstream. It loses precision when I use it to convert string to double.

```
const std::string str = "44.23331002";
double x;
stringstream ss;
ss << str;
ss >> x;
cout << str << " = " << x << endl;
```

The output is:
**44.23331002 = 44.2333**

Why is this? Does it convert to float and has limited digit precision?

Comment: You take a tiny rounding error when converting from string to double, but the real issue is how you're converting from double to string.

Comment: well, floating point is not the most precise thing ever. if you must have the presicion, parse it yourself with a simple loop. even then, small precision bugs may occur

Comment: Look at std::setprecision and std::ios_base::precision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the precision on the output stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const std::string str = "44.23331002";
    double x;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    ss >> x;
    cout << str << " = " << std::setprecision(10) << x << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
44.23331002 = 44.23331002
```

[(Demo)](http://ideone.com/kwgPOZ)

Comment: Ahh, so the problem is on the cout's side. I thought the converting fails here.

Comment: @Grzyboo - the problem is in the round-trip conversion to text and back; the outgoing conversion has six digits of precision, so that's all that's present in the incoming conversion. Neither conversion is wrong, but the combination doesn't do what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

calcto answered correctly.and You can change precision in two way:
`std::setprecision(10)` and `std::cout.precision(10)`